# Help understanding multiplying matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm getting stuck on multiplying matrices together and cannot figure out for the life of me where I'm going wrong.

I'm working on some robotics and reading through a textbook which gives the following example of matrices:

[image]

This gives me a transformation matrix for each joint in a robot, which then gets multiplied together to give a rotational matrix for all 3 joints together.

[image]

When actually doing this multiplication myself, I always come up with the same incorrect matrix.

I start by multiplying A4 * A5 which I get matrix A45 as:

[image]

I then multiply A45 x A6 and get this:

[image]

R12, R21 and R22 have signs that do not match the example.

To multiply, I'm summing the product of each element in a row for the first matrix by each element in a column for the second matrix:

[image]

I feel like I'm doing it right and it just doesn't make sense to me how I'm getting different sign values. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I think you're right and the textbook contains an error. One way to double check would be to choose random values for the various constants and multiply the matrices in Python.

Comment: Its weird because I have another example from another paper that I also get a different answer on so I figured I was doing something wrong. 
Do you happen to know what the little dot next to the A6 and T36 matrices mean? They use that notation throughout the textbook and I can't find anything on it. I will verify with a matrix library that my results are correct.

Comment: That little dot is just a period marking the end of a sentence.

Comment: Figured it was some weird math symbol lol, that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: Your computed value for the 2nd entry in the top row is correct; the " supposed" value is wrong. Somehow a plus sign became a minus.